# Comprehension with chained for statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I am supposed to take an array x and an array y, and make a new array of pairs such that the elements are not equal. Here is my code:

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[2,4,6]
my_list=[]
for a in x:
    for b in y:
        if a!=b:
            list=[a,b]
            my_list.append(list)
#my_list+=[(a,b) for (a,b) in (x,y) if (a!=b)]
print (my_list)
```

Thus, the output is: `[[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 6], [2, 4], [2, 6], [3, 2], [3, 4], [3, 6], [4, 2], [4, 6]]`

Without importing anything, how do I collapse this with list comprehension AND chained for statements. My meager attempt is in the #comment section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can do it using a list comprehension:

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[2,4,6]

[[a,b] for a in x for b in y if a!=b]
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 6], [2, 4], [2, 6], [3, 2], [3, 4], [3, 6], [4, 2], [4, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was so close in all my attempts, but this is most straightforward. I wish Python made list comprehension syntax easier.

Comment: @user5179531 don't forget to accept the answer if it helped, thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid creating x and y variables by writing the following code

`[[i, j] for i in [1, 2, 3, 4] for j in [2, 4, 6] if i != j]`

Comment: It's better to have variables for the lists, in case that they're pretty big. You don't get extra points for using less variables ;)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I can't understand your comment. Are you saying that is better to have two for loops than a python contraction or are you talking about the name of "i", "j" variables? I think python contractions are very pythonic way to loop through arrays and are very accepted for all python community.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I agree, but this is just one more way of doing it.

Comment: The question I was working on asked for them to be variables, so they can be changed at will. Writing them explicitly into the code "hardwires" them. Thats why I used x and y.

Comment: @Nico that's not what I'm saying, at all. I'm not even talking about comprehensions (not contractions as you say). I'm only talking about variable names.

Answer (score -1):

This is also a where you can make use of `itertools` to build the output.  Gets you the same output as a list comprehension, but with a little less code.

```
import itertools

x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[2,4,6]

list(itertools.product(x, y))
```